# One Outlook 2016, two profiles, two mailboxes: but Outlook tries connecting to both

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am using Outlook 2016 (fully updated) on Windows 8.1 to access an outlook.com (actually outlook.it) mailbox and an Office 365 mailbox; I created two Outlook profiles, each one connecting to one of those mailboxes.

When opening the outlook.it profile, Outlook also tries to connect also to the Office 365 mailbox, *although it belongs to a different profile*; thus Outlook continuously prompts for authentication, because of course the credentials for one mailbox don't work for the other one.

As it can be seen from this screenshot, Outlook actually tries connecting to both mailboxes, although this doesn't make the slightest bit of sense, because each profile only contains one of them (the red rows belong to the outlook.it mailbox, the blue ones to the Office 365 mailbox):

[image]

The opposite doesn't happen; when opening the Office 365 profile, Outlook only connects to the Office 365 mailbox.

Why is this happening, and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was caused by one of the the Outlook profiles (the one for the Office 365 mailbox) being set as the default one; as soon as I configured Outlook (via the Control Panel settings) to not have a default profile, it stopped mixing them.